# Use variable from a function in another PHP

Tags: php, function, oop

I have a question. How do I do to rescue the variable $row in this function ListarGeral(). so I can use the function EditarGeral() . I tried to do, but nothing happened

here's what I tried to do:

```
<?php
include ('Banco.php');

Class GeralControle {

    private $consulta;
    private $row = array();

    public function GeraloDao() {
        $novaconexao = new Banco();
        $this->consulta = $novaconexao->conectar(); 
    }

    public function ListarGeral() {

        $this->GeraloDao();
        echo '<table border="1" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
            <td>CPF</td>
        </tr>';

        if ($resultado = $this->consulta->query("select * from cadastro")) {    

            while ($this->row = $resultado->fetch_row()) {
                echo '<tr>
                        <td>'.$this->row[0].'</td>
                        <td>'.$this->row[1].'</td>
                    </tr>';
                echo $this->row[0];
            }
            $resultado->close();
        }   
        echo '</table>';
    }

    public function EditarGeral(){
        $this->ListarGeral();
        echo $this->row[0];
    }
}


$pessoa2 = new GeralControle();
$pessoa2->ListarGeral();

$pessoa3 = new GeralControle();
$pessoa3->EditarGeral();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Well, presumably you'll want to `return` some value at the end of `ListarGeral()` and then access it doing something like `$returnValue = $this->ListarGeral();` Since `ListarGeral()` iterates over many rows though, I'm not sure what exactly you want or expect to be returned. The last row?

Comment: I want to access the variable $row and another function

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ($resultado = $this->consulta->query("select * from cadastro")) {    
               $rows = array();

                while ($this->row = $resultado->fetch_row()) {
                    echo '<tr>
                            <td>'.$this->row[0].'</td>
                            <td>'.$this->row[1].'</td>
                          </tr>
                        ';echo $this->row[0];
                        array_push($rows, $this->row);
                }
                EditarGeral($rows);
}
```

Comment: I almost got what vocêd did, it now appears the value of the variable $ row in another function, but also appears this error:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Comment: $this->row will be pushed to $rows. (rows is plural from row and ends with the letter s)  $rows = array(); // init array